# How to Build Pre-Master Secret

Tags: tls, sha, diffie-hellman, ecc

I'm implementing a TLS-like system, which uses `ECDHE-RSA-AE-GCM-SHA`, and I've faced two interrogations.

At the end of the handshake ( and before the `ChangeCipherSpec` message), both the client and the server have to build the same `Pre-Master Secret`.

**On what  data is based this secret ?** Since I haven't found the answer in the RFS's ([4492](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4492) and [5246](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246)), I'd say this :

- the Server Public ECDHE Key (send within `ServerKeyExchange` message)
- the Client Public ECDHE Key (sent, ciphered, with the `ClientKeyExchange` message)

It's, for me, the logical components, since *Mallory* couldn't retrieve the Client Public ECDHE Key, because encrypted with the server PublicKey. If yes, the signature of the `ServerkeyExchange` message would be wrong, and the Client would know that attempt.

*I'm aware that this isn't a proper justification at all, and, when speaking of cryptography, these kinds of reasoning are bad (when not wrong), but since I haven't found the answer in the RFC, all what's left is here...*

And moreover, **what algorithm do we use** to actually build the Pre-Master secret ? Is it a classical hash function (SHA, ...) ?

I know that `SHA` is used for expanding the `MasterSecret` (from the random numbers and the `Pre-Patser Secret`), but for its little brother I'm in the fog...

Comment: I want to mention that writing your own crypto is hard and writing secure crypto is really hard. If there's anyway you can use an existing, well-tested system, you'll likely be better off.

Comment: @RoraZ 81597 is mostly about the derivation of masterkey and working keys for TLS1.0 and 1.1, not TLS1.2 as referenced here. EisenHeim: the key-derivation uses MD5 *and* SHA1 in SSL3 and TLS1.0 and 1.1 but in TLS1.2 it uses SHA256 for most ciphersuites and SHA384 for a few. But the *premaster* for ECDHE or ECDH is specified in rfc4492 5.10: "the premaster secret is the x-coordinate of
   the ECDH shared secret elliptic curve point represented as an octet
   string".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"ECDHE" means "ephemeral [Diffie-Hellman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_key_exchange) (with elliptic curves)". This is what the pre-master secret comes from. The client generates a random DH key pair (a DH private key and the corresponding public key). The server also generates a random DH key pair. They send to each other the public parts of their respective key pairs.

The client uses its private DH key, combined with the DH public key from the server, to obtain the premaster secret.

The server uses its private DH key, combined with the DH public key from the client, to obtain the premaster secret.

By the magic of Diffie-Hellman, they both obtain the same value for the premaster secret. But, still by that magic, eavesdroppers, who only saw the public keys from both client and server but no private DH key at all, cannot rebuild the premaster secret.

("ciphered" is not a word; you probably mean "encrypted". But no, there is no encryption here. The DH public keys are *public* and, indeed, sent as-is over the wire.)

Comment: OK, thanks ! I though we had to use a specific algorithm to compute the Pre-Master Secret. And sorry for *cipher*, in french we have a difference between "chiffrer" and "crypter"...

Comment: "Crypter" is not a French word either (although its use is widespread). The correct terms are _chiffrer_ and _déchiffrer_. There is also _décrypter_, which means obtaining the plaintext without knowning the key (i.e. breaking through the encryption systems). The terms _crypter_ and _encrypter_ are tentative imports from the corresponding English terms, but they are not proper. Beware the wrath of the _Académie française_ !

Comment: Yeah that's what I wanted to explain :P Did that too fast :)